# kubernetes-helm: formating do-block-storage with xfs format

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-helm

i am trying to create mongodb-replicaset with kubernetes-helm on digitalocean using do-block-storage. since mongodb recommended to use xfs format, i try to format do-block-storage with xfs using configuration like below, but it seem didn't work. can you help? thank you.

```
persistentVolume:
  enabled: true
  ## mongodb-replicaset data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  storageClass: "do-block-storage"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  size: 10Gi
  parameters:
    fsType: xfs
  annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your custom parameters (values.yaml):

1. MongoDB stable Helm chart does not know anything about user-defined field: "parameters". This is because it simply is not defined in any template file (mongodb/templates/*.yaml). In your case Helm will render a similar file to this:

> `volumeClaimTemplates:
>       - metadata:
>           name: datadir
>           annotations:
>         spec:
>           accessModes:
>             - "ReadWriteOnce"
>           resources:
>             requests:
>               storage: "10Gi"
>           storageClassName: "do-block-storage"`

2. You can't specify "fsType" in volumeClaimTemplates, although it was once requested (see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44478) github issue).

I can see two possible workarounds for your issue:

1. Use a separate StorageClass, with default xfs filesystem format, and then reference its name in helm chart`s values, e.g. create **do-block-storage-xfs** StorageClass liek this:

> `kind: StorageClass
>   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
>   metadata:
>     name: do-block-storage-xfs
>     namespace: kube-system
>     annotations:
>       storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
>   provisioner: com.digitalocean.csi.dobs
>   parameters:
>     fstype: xfs`

2. Create in advance a Persistent Volume in DigitalOcean of xfs fsType & PVC in K8S, and reference it as an existing PVC in the Helm chart (see *persistence.existingClaim* configurable parameter [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb))